# Can I show the time spent in the currently active task in my orgmode clocktable?

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, org-clock-table

When I press `R` in my orgmode agenda to view the clocktable (or `v R` for clockReport), I get a list of clock times for **finished** tasks.  Is it possible to also show the time so far spent on the **currently active** task (i.e., the time shown in the modeline), and include it in the total work time today?  If so, how can I do that?

Currently, if I want to see how many hours I have worked so far today, I have to clock out of and into my current task and then refresh the clocktable.

Comment: it doesn't appear on modeline?

Comment: @Muihlinn Yes, but not in the clocktable.  I could add the time to the total it myself, but that's what the clocktable is supposed to do :-)

Comment: oh, that was enough - and better - to me. I've submitted a response to include it in the clock report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shoud set `org-clock-report-include-clocking-task` to non-nil for that.

It's a `defcustom` so just using `setq` might not work. It didn't for me.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!   And `setq` does seem to work for me.

Comment: I meant that either use customize interface, `custom-set-variables` or `use-package`'s `:custom` to set it, that's the safe way, just in case that it has a setter, something I haven't checked for.